# I have an angular app and some elements can not find with cypress

Tags: angular, cypress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pauNn.png)I am using cypress to automate our angular app but it is not finding some elements which are under a special div
it is behaving like it is iframe outside this div i can locate elements.
I checked there is no iframe tag. is there some other features in angular which behaves like iframe .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8x68.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand the basics of Cypress, but maybe there is another problem. Can't help with some clues about the page and the test you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there is shadow DOM present.

Add this to `cypress.json`

```js
{
  ...
  "includeShadowDom": true
}
```

Comment: i figure out the problem but still can not solve it.Cypress test runner puts an iframe inside html but i tried  cy.frameLoaded and cy.iframe  but every time got  "Expected to find element: .iframes-container, but never found it." in my normal html there is no iframe my app is angular

Comment: No, that's not the problem. The iframe you refer to is used by Cypress to apply commands to your app. Don't try to access inside it, the test already does it for you.